# How can I add a symbol panel as in github page in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Since I need many variables I want to track how I am using them in my python code, as I can watch them in the github page, as in the picture in the rigth side:

[image: Symbol Explorer]

I've been looking for something similar on the extensions store as well as in the VS Code page, but I haven't been able to find anythig useful.

Comment: Are you aware of the [Outline](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_outline-view)?

Comment: Yep, but that it's not what I am looking for.

Comment: @starball Branching off of that, I found out there's a References sidebar panel and you can open a particular symbol in it with Shift+Alt+F12. It doesn't seem to show all symbols, just ones you've searched for (at least with Python with Jedi), but at least it's closer to what OP's looking for.